# jQuery Draggable area (Circle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to build a kind of joystick, so the inner picture (my draggable object) should have a specific range. Currently it's just a squarde and I don't like that!

I found the possibility to control moves by returning true or false in my drag-method but if I return false the object jumps back to its start instead of standing still :(

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your drag handler you have change the position. If your draggable tries to go outside of the container that you want to keep it in, then just truncate the position back within the container and don't return false.

[Draggable API docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

Comment: Mh.. I want it to jump back if the user releases it.

Comment: Also my button is frozen after this because I returned false but did not change the position :P

Comment: The draggable is getting broken if I try that :/

         `drag: function (event, ui) {
                    if (updatePositionInfo() < 30) {
                        var pos = ui.position;
                        lastValidX = pos.top;
                        lastValidY = pos.left;`

Answer (score 0):

I think the **containment** option will be there when you want to restrict your object in particular area. see below link for reference.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-containment